# Call a different REST endpoint per Gatsby Page

Tags: rest, graphql, gatsby

I'm writing a Gatsby Plugin to consume an HTML-returning service. The relevant endpoint changes based on each Gatsby page I'm creating. Specifically, this is based on locale-

- `homepage.com` needs to call out to `service.com/en`
- `homepage.es` needs to call out to `service.com/es`

etc.

I can pass the locale into my context from my project's `gatsby-node.js`, which makes it available in my page's `index.js` and GraphQL query, but I can't figure out how to capture that variable in the plugin.

```
// project/gatsby-node.js
export.createPages = () => {Locales.forEach(locale => {
  createPage({
    component: myComponent.js,
    context: {
        locale: locale
    },
  })
})
```

```
// project/page.js
export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.data.header.innerHtml}}></div>
  );
}

export const query = graphql`
query {
  header(locale: $locale) { // my understanding is that this should pass it to the GraphQL query
    innerHtml    
  }
}`
```

```
// plugin/gatsby-node.js
exports.sourceNodes = async ({ boundActionCreators }, configOptions) => {
  const { createNode } = boundActionCreators;

  const fetchHtml = () => axios.get(configOptions.htmlServerUrl); // I need to append to the path here
  // await for results
  const res = await fetchHtml();

  const htmlNode = {
    id: "html",
    internal: {
      type: `html`
    },
    innerHtml: res.data,
  };

  return createNode(htmlNode);
}
```

I've heard that I need a bulk endpoint on the REST service which I can then filter. Is that true? **How do I modify the HTTP call sent for each different page?**

Comment: I think you'd need to fetch all locales, then pass the `locale` variable into the graphql query instead of passing the `locale` to the plugin

Comment: also it should be `query GetLocale($locale: String) { header { innerHTML } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem with a custom resolver. We built a plugin that extended the Query syntax:

```
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }, configOptions) => {
  createResolvers({
    Query: {
      [configOptions.name]: {
        type: `String`,
        args: {
          locale: 'String'
        },
        resolve: async (source, args, context, info) => {
          const {
            htmlServerUrl,
            defaultResponse
          } = configOptions;
          return axios
            .get(`${htmlServerUrl}?args.locale`)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .catch(err => defaultResponse || "");
        },
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Then `gatsby-config` looks like this:

```
{
  resolve: "my-plugin",
  options: {
    htmlServerUrl: `http://my.html-service.com`,
    name: "header"
  }
}
```

Finally, this is used in a component:

```
query($locale: String) {
  header(locale: $locale)
}
```

Comment: why not use `context` passed to `resolve: async (source, args, context, info)` - it should contain `locale` - w/o using params/args?

Comment: What would be the advantage of that?

Comment: not much, no need for `locale` in query, a bit cleaner query and code